# Access to FTP server tunnelled through two remote servers

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, ftp

I have a remote server, which has a VPN connection to a Raspberry running as a home server, connected to my local LAN. I can SSH into this with a tunnel through my remote server to wake up my desktop, on my desktop there is a FTP server running.

I want to access this FTP server from my Linux machine remotely. How do I do this efficiently? I think connecting my desktop to the VPN would be okay. I read about Socks proxies but can't get them working with two hops and ftp.

Comment: Seems like you already have it setup in a efficient way, have the FTP server sit inside your LAN and use your VPN to access it. With the setup you have right now, it would be pointless to expose your FTP server publicly unless if you're the only one using it.

Comment: I don't want to expose my FTP server, but I want to not have to add all my devices to the VPN. I do all this stuff to bypass a restriction on port forwarding from my ISP. Basically, I'd like to just tunnel through the remote server to the home server to access the FTP. Is that possible?